# android:junit running Parameterized testcases

Tags: android, junit, parameterized

i wan to run a single testcase with different parameters.
in java
it possible through junit4 and code is like this

```
package com.android.test;


import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;




@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTestExample {

    private int number;
    private int number2;
    private int result;
    private functioncall coun;

    //constructor takes parameters from array
    public ParameterizedTestExample(int number, int number2,
            int result1) {
        this.number = number;
        this.number2 = number2;
        this.result = result1;
        coun = new functioncall();
    }

    //array with parameters
    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1, 4, 5 }, { 2, 7, 9 },
                { 3, 7, 10 }, { 4, 9, 13 } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }
    //running our test    
    @Test
    public void testCounter() {
        assertEquals("Result add x y", result, coun.calculateSum(this.number,  this.number2), 0);
    }
}
```

Now my question is can we Run the same with android testcases where we have deal with context.

when i try to run the code using android junit.
it gives me error NoClassDefinationFound.

Comment: What is "android junit"? Which class is not defined?

Comment: Actuly i have android project in that i have android testcase, i need to run that test case with different parameter like shown above in java  parmeterized testcase class.above given annotation like "@Test" and "@Parameters" are defined in junit 4, where as android uses junit3 for running testcase, so is there any way by which i can run the android testcase like above.